# How to update cart value 'in real time' in Cart Fragment(Android)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-fragments

I am working on an Ecommerce app. I have come to the first problem I don't know how to tackle, I want to update Cart Value without having to reenter Cart Fragment so if somebody removes a product from the Cart, Cart Value should go down immediately straight away. I have tried several different approaches but none seem to be working.
Users add products to cart in Product Detail fragment -> User goes to cart and sees products in cart via Recycler View -> I have a field with Total Price that is not a part of a recycler. This field does not update when I remove products from cart and I know it cannot do it as of now, cannot figure out how to do it.
I'm using Firebase Cloud to get User and Product data.

Cart Fragment

```
    class CartFragment : RootFragment(), OnProductClick {

    private val cartViewModel by viewModels<CartFragmentViewModel>()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentCartBinding
    private val adapter = CartAdapter(this)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_cart,
            container,
            false
        )

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.recyclerCart.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        binding.recyclerCart.adapter = adapter
        binding.buttonToCheckout.setOnClickListener {
            navigateToCheckout()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        cartViewModel.userCart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { list ->

                adapter.setCartProducts(list)
                val cartQuantity = list.size
                binding.textCartQuantityValue.text = cartQuantity.toString()

                val cartValue = cartViewModel.calculateCartValue(list)
                binding.textCartTotalValue.text = cartValue.toString()
        })

    }

    // TODO
    override fun onProductClick(product: Product, position: Int) {
        cartViewModel.removeFromCart(product)
        adapter.removeFromCart(product, position)
    }
}
```

Cart View Model

```
    class CartFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = FirebaseCloud()
    private val user = repository.getUserData()


    val userCart = user.switchMap {
        repository.getProductsFromCart(it.cart)
    }

    fun calculateCartValue(list: List<Product>): Long {

        var cartValue = 0L

        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (product in list) {
                cartValue += product.price!!
            }
        }

        return cartValue
    }

    fun removeFromCart(product: Product) {
        repository.removeFromCart(product)
    }
}
```

Cart Adapter

```
    class CartAdapter(private val listener: OnProductClick) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder>() {

    private val cartList = ArrayList<Product>()

    fun setCartProducts(list: List<Product>) {
        cartList.clear()
        cartList.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeFromCart(product: Product, position: Int) {
        cartList.remove(product)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartViewHolder {

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_cart, parent, false)
        return CartViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        bindCartData(holder)
    }

    private fun bindCartData(holder: CartViewHolder) {
        val name = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_product_name_cart)
        val price = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_product_price_cart)
        val image = holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_product_image_cart)

        name.text = cartList[holder.adapterPosition].name
        price.text = cartList[holder.adapterPosition].price.toString()
        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
            .load(cartList[holder.adapterPosition].imageUrl)
            .into(image)
     }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return cartList.size
    }

    inner class CartViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.button_remove_from_cart)
                .setOnClickListener{
                    listener.onProductClick(cartList[adapterPosition], adapterPosition)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this using data binding on the xml side? Using one-way data binding, you can set a value on an attribute and set a listener that reacts to a change in that attribute.

Comment: Have you tried to use Firebase-UI and always stay in sync with the Firebase servers?

Comment: you can update your cart in two ways : 1. client side 2. server side. Which way you are doing or planning to do

Comment: Thank you all! Ideally I wanted to use observer in the Cart Fragment and I was hoping when value of the userCart changes, observer will just run the code again this is not working and I guess I need to learn much more about Observers.

I will definetely give a try to one-way data binding, sound goods.
And I want to update my cart both ways, removeFromCart() should remove a product from Firebase User and from list used in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with not so elegant way and if someone has tips how to use the observer I already have observer in Cart Fragment it would be awesome.
What I've done is I updated onProductClick() in Cart Fragment to recalculate the value once again.

```
override fun onProductClick(product: Product, position: Int) {
    cartViewModel.removeFromCart(product)
    adapter.removeFromCart(product, position)

    val productsInCart = adapter.cartList
    val cartValue = cartViewModel.calculateCartValue(productsInCart)
    binding.textCartTotalValue.text = cartValue.toString()
    binding.textCartQuantityValue.text = productsInCart.size.toString()
}
```